# Rectangle SVG Masking over video tag

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a Mask over video tag.

I have below svg element which has transparent text but I am looking to have a rectangle shape instead of text.

I have also tried with polygon to create a rectangle but seems its not working.

```
<polygon points="0 0,0 100,300 100,300 0" fill="orange" />
    

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 285 80" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice">
    <defs>
    <mask id="mask" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" >
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" />
    <text x="72"  y="50">OCEAN</text>
      </mask>
  </defs>
 <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" />
  </svg>


        svg { 
      width: 100%;
      position:absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0; // needed for FF, Safari, Edge
      height: 100%;
    }
    svg text {
      font-family: Biko, sans-serif;
      font-weight: 700;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-size: 38px;
    }
    svg rect {
      fill: white;
    }
    svg > rect {
        -webkit-mask: url(#mask);
        mask: url(#mask);
        -webkit-mask-mode: alpha;
       mask-mode: alpha;
      fill: black;
      fill-opacity:0.8;
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to achieve using another rect element inside mask.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 285 80" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice">
    <defs>
    <mask id="mask" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" >
      <rect id="svg-rect" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" />
    <rect x="100" y="10" rx="5" ry="5" width="60" height="30"/>
     
      </mask>
  </defs>
 <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" />
  </svg>
```